# FrameLayout and LinearLayout, draw button on bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout

there are a tons of different suggestions for this but none of them seem to work (although I might be doing it wrong) with layout:gravity etc etc.

I wish to draw my buttons on the bottom of the screen, as opposed to them being drawn at a default position on the top of the screen. I'm sure there is an easy way of doing it.

At the moment, the buttons draw on the top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:game_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pap.crowslanding"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <pap.crowslanding.GameView
        android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth"
        game_view:pixelHeight="@dimen/pixelHeight"
        game_view:pixelWidth="@dimen/pixelWidth" />

    <pap.crowslanding.MazeBall
        android:id="@+id/mazeball"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/right" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/down" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent container is a `RelativeLayout`, so you just need to add `android:android:layout_alignParentBottom=true` to your `LinearLayout` and get rid of that `layout_gravity` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much, can't believe I didn't try that!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:game_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/pap.crowslanding"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <pap.crowslanding.GameView
        android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth"
        game_view:pixelHeight="@dimen/pixelHeight"
        game_view:pixelWidth="@dimen/pixelWidth" />

    <pap.crowslanding.MazeBall
        android:id="@+id/mazeball"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        game_view:ballDiam="@dimen/ballDiam"
        game_view:cellWidth="@dimen/cellWidth" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/right" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/down" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you will need to adjust your buttons so that they are not on top of each other (`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_name"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf=...`). I didn't know which you wanted right and left. Also you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. `fill_parent` was deprecated in API 8 (I think it was 8, but I know it was deprecated).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it works as intended, however, the right button(button1) just draws ontop of button2, I would like button1 on the left hand side and button2 on the right hand side, however, when I implement android:layout_toLeftOf=button2).RelativeLayout doesn't like setting a layout for an object that hasn't been created yet

Comment: put `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"` on button2 and then on button1 you could put `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`